# How to run 'pythondialog' codes under Windows？

Tags: python, dialog

I am learning pythondialog recently.I try to run the examples codes from here：http://pythondialog.sourceforge.net/#installation

This is the code：

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import locale
from dialog import Dialog

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
d = Dialog(dialog="dialog")
d.set_background_title("My little program")
if d.yesno("Are you REALLY sure you want to see this?") == d.OK:
    d.msgbox("You have been warned...")
    code, tags = d.checklist("What sandwich toppings do you like?",
                         choices=[("Catsup", "",             False),
                                  ("Mustard", "",            False),
                                  ("Pesto", "",              False),
                                  ("Mayonnaise", "",         True),
                                  ("Horse radish","",        True),
                                  ("Sun-dried tomatoes", "", True)],
                         title="Do you prefer ham or spam?",
                         backtitle="And now, for something "
                         "completely different...")
    if code == d.OK:
        pass
else:
    code, tag = d.menu("OK, then you have two options:",
                   choices=[("(1)", "Leave this fascinating example"),
                            ("(2)", "Leave this fascinating example")])
    if code == d.OK:
        pass
```

It can be working under linux--debian,when i used "apt install python3-dialog".If i only pip install 'pythondialog',the program error:'ExecutableNotFound...'

Now i am trying to run the codes under windows10 use the pycharm,but there is the same error :

```
...  
File "D:\PycharmProjects\test\venv\lib\site-packages\dialog.py", line 469, in _path_to_executable
"can't find the executable for the dialog-like "
dialog.ExecutableNotFound: Executable not found: can't find the executable for the dialog-like program
```

I think i seem to install the 'exe' about dialog(),but i don't know how to do it.
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please put the code in pastebin instead of showing it in an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear: “Executable not found: can't find the executable for the dialog-like program”. pythondialog works by calling the [dialog](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) program. However, the name of the called program is not important, what matters is that it *behaves* like dialog; therefore, any program that is compatible with dialog is fine. A program that accepts the same command-line arguments as dialog and behaves similarly when given the same command-line arguments is called a *dialog-like program* in the pythondialog documentation ([manual](http://pythondialog.sourceforge.net/doc/) and other pages or files).

So, pythondialog requires a dialog-like program as we just defined. By default, it looks for this program under the name `dialog` using the `PATH` environment variable, but you can explicitly choose a specific name or full path to an executable if you prefer. For instance, if you have a dialog-like program called `foobar` that is present in one of the directories of your `PATH`, constructing the `Dialog` instance with `Dialog(dialog="foobar")` will make it so that all widgets displayed using methods of this object will use `foobar` instead of [dialog](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) as the underlying engine.

The reason you didn't have the error when you used `apt install python3-dialog` on Debian is that the `python3-dialog` Debian package depends on the `dialog` Debian package. Therefore, you had a dialog-like program installed under the default name `dialog` in one of the directories of your `PATH` (normally in `/usr/bin`, unless you had something *else* called `dialog` earlier in your PATH, for instance a local installation of [dialog](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html)).

However, when you tried to use pythondialog on Windows, you didn't fulfill the basic requirement of having a dialog-like program installed, that is why you got the “Executable not found” error. The [PyPI page for pythondialog](https://pypi.org/project/pythondialog/) says “Operating system: Unix” because [dialog](https://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html) requires an Unix (or POSIX) terminal to run, AFAIK. Thus, it isn't very surprising that pythondialog doesn't work natively on Windows. However, it is likely to work under Windows *inside Cygwin*. Indeed, it appears that dialog has been ported to Cygwin; you would need to install this port, of course, and at least run your program inside a Cygwin terminal (I'm not sure if the Python installation must also be a Cygwin port in this case, so you might want to try with the native Python under Windows, but be sure to run your program from a terminal provided by Cygwin).

Comment: Thank you for your answer sincerely, sorry for not replying in time.
I tried running it under Cygwin and it worked!
The following are the required environments:
1. install `python3.8` and `pip3` package in Cygwin environment (not under windows10, pythondialog uses `os.fork()`, but there is no `os.fork()` under windows)
2. Install `dialog` package in Cygwin environment
3. `pip3 install pythondialog`